# Changing highlited color of the image

Tags: ios, image, colors, uibutton, storyboard

I have an UIButton with image in it. When it pressed image is highlited, and it is good. But it highlited with a **gray** color. I want for example red or green. What should I change in StoryBoard or in the code?

Comment: You should post your code and what you have tried so far so we can better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

How about Highlight Tint? [image]

It's in the Attributes Inspector for the button